# FB.api javascript responding denied in jsf

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, jsf-2.2

I am using jsf 2.2 . I am trying to implement fb-Login in my jsf project. When i call FB.api the access is denied. In order to get response from FB.api how should I configure my project? Here I have attached my javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<h:head>
    <title>FB Login</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'appID',
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here

            FB.api('/platform', function(response) {
                alert(response.company_overview);
            });

            showMe = function(response) {
                if (response.status !== 'connected') {
                    div.innerHTML = '<em>Not Connected</em>';
                } else {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        var i=0;
                        for (var key in response) {
                            i++;
                            switch(i){
                                case 1: document.getElementById("frm:id").value=response[key]; break;
                                case 2: document.getElementById("frm:name").value=response[key]; break;
                                case 3: document.getElementById("frm:firstName").value=response[key]; break;
                                case 4: document.getElementById("frm:lastName").value=response[key]; break;
                                case 5: document.getElementById("frm:link").value=response[key]; break;
                                case 6: document.getElementById("frm:userName").value=response[key]; break;
                                case 7: document.getElementById("frm:email").value=response[key];  break;
                            }  
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                showMe(response);
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', showMe);
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>
    <div id="fbsignin-button" class="show">
        <fb:login-button scope="email"></fb:login-button>
    </div>
    <h:form id="frm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="id" value="ID : "/>
            <h:inputText id="id" value="#{FbLoginBean.id}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name : "/>
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{FbLoginBean.name}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First Name : "/>
            <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#FbLoginBean.firstName}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="lastName" value="Last Name : "/>
            <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{FbLoginBean.lastName}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="link" value="Link : "/>
            <h:inputText id="link" value="#{FbLoginBean.link}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="userName" value="User Name : "/>
            <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{FbLoginBean.userName}" />
            <h:inputHidden id="email" value="#{FbLoginBean.email}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Register"
                action="#{FbLoginBean.fbDisplay}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: could anybody help me?

Comment: I am not getting any error, instead my FB-Login button not rendering in my web portal.

Comment: If you open some browser console, do you get any log messages?

Comment: It showing an error message as, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Answer (score 1):

about Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } 
As I see in the `<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#FbLoginBean.firstName}" />` there is no `{` after `#`